# Twig templating for variables and filters

Tags: twig, octobercms

Having problems with correct output in October CMS twig:
Using -

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/img/flag-'~code~'.png'|theme) }}" class="flag">
```

And expecting 
http://xxx.dev/themes/theme/assets/img/flag-en.png in the src, however I'm getting
http://xxx.dev/assets/img/flag-enhttp://xxx.dev/themes/theme/.png instead...

How can I solve this?

Comment: images are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (notice the parenthesis):

```
<img src="{{ asset(('assets/img/flag-'~code~'.png')|theme) }}" class="flag">
```

And the logic begind it is that the `|theme` is applied only to the `.png´ part and therefore it generates a broken url.